# Migrating Wordpress including Widgets and Media Files

Tags: wordpress, migration

I have created a wordpress website on the localhost and want to migrate it to the clients server. How can i shift the content, images (media) and the theme and its widgets.

Hope i dont have to recreate all that on the website all over again :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BackupBuddy is probably the most efficient and easiest way.  Here's the URL: [BackupBuddy](http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/)

Plenty of documentation and the plugin basically does everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Review the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) on this issue for details and various [Tools](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) that can help you.
2. Make sure that your theme and widgets are not referencing the old domain directly. If this is a theme/plugin/widget of your own making, you should be aware that Wordpress has [Various Functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) that reference the URL of your Wordpress installation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a few things:

1. Install WP Migrate DB http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-migrate-db/ and use it to export the DB as a gzip file
2. Upload all the Wordpress files to the server modifying wp-config.php to match the client's  MySql server. If WP is already installed, upload only what's in wp-content
3. Access the client's MySql server (normally through phpMyAdmin) and import the gzip file that contains your DB

To get the server path on the client's server (WP Migrate DB will ask for it) use this php snippet from the site's / :

```
<?php print_r(__DIR__) ?>
```

That should be it.

Cheers.